# Originating direction of shots in an FPS problem

Tags: game-mechanics, first-person-shooter

Recently I have been asked on the interview about a maybe simple task to solve a problem.

We have a player, that looks in some direction, and a shooter, who already is shooting the player. I must find out whether the shots come from the left or right in the same way Counter Strike does when you get hit: the game shows from which direction and it looks like a red half-circle.

I know the vectors of players and enemies position. I tried different answers f.e. to build a line from the player see's and solve a linear system equation or rotate the player vector and then find out the angle of scalar product, but he says there's a better way to do it. I don't need the answer to this particular question, but a 'way' to find out the answer. F.e. any books related to this problems, some similar problems, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem: Get the dot product of the player's left direction with the direction from the player to the shooter. That'll be positive if the shooter is to the player's left, or negative if the shooter is to the player's right.

In general, learn about useful linear algebra operations like dot and cross product. Start here http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-2/

Comment: So, the answer is just like I said, to rotate the player vision to the left and get dot(scalar) product with the shooting player?

Comment: oh is that what you meant by "build a line from the player see's and solve a linear system equation" that sounded like word-soup to me

Comment: That was another variant of solving :) "rotate the player vector and then find out the angle of scalar product", that was in the question, that i mentioned.

Comment: or does "rotate the player vector and then find out the angle of scalar product" mean to use the dot product? Perhaps that was your actual error; you knew the method, but didn't really explain what you meant (eg. you never used the term "dot product"; "scalar product" is technically a synonym, but referring to it as an angle threw me)

Comment: Maybe it was, cause I can't think of other possible good answers :( When I explained this, he(interviewer) told that rotation around the vector itself is bad. And this put me against the wall.

Comment: There again, I didn't understand what you meant by "rotate the player vector" so maybe he didn't either. I mean, in this situation the relevant vector would simply be (-1, 0, 0) so I'm not sure what you meant by rotating the vector.

Comment: In your answer "player's left direction", to get left direction you must rotate the vector to left.  "the relevant vector would simply be (-1, 0, 0)" if the player isn't at the start, the coords woudn't be like that, that's why I told rotate left. And then you find the dot product of these 2 vectors.

Comment: I wouldn't describe that as "rotating" the vector, but as transforming the player's left from local to world coordinates. (-1, 0, 0) is left in local coordinates, so that needs to be transformed to world coordinates. Semantics I suppose, but then interview questions sometimes hinge on semantics.

Comment: Thx for answering